# Can't View Usage Quota for Google API

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-directions-api

I am currently implementing Google Maps and Google Directions in my iOS application, and I want to be able to view my usage/quotas, but in my Google Developer Console, when I go to overview, all the statistics say that I have made `0` request, even though I certainly have.

In my Xcode project, in ***AppDelegate.swift*** I have included:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // Google SDK.
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")

    return true
}
```

In the function where I create the URL to get the `JSON` results from Google servers, I have the following snippet:

```
var directionsURLString = baseURLDirections + "origin=" + originLocation + "&destination=" + destinationLocation + "&mode=walking"
```

I want to point out that I intentionally left out my API key in the URL because it was causing errors with retrieving the JSON results.

Comment: Hey, similar problem here, did you found any solution?